# AngularJS : Change the element associated with directive using transclude

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

How can I change the element associated with a call to `transclude()`?

In my app, I dynamically load an entire SVG file from the server and display it. I need to add behaviors to the loaded content.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
<div svg-canvas="urlToSVGContent"></div>
```

This loads an SVG tag inside the div. This works great, but what if I want to add an ng-click to every `<path>`, `<circle>`, etc? `ng-click` already works on svg paths out of the box, it's just a question of referencing the element somehow.

I can already make a directive using transclude that will run once for each path:

```
<div svg-canvas="urlToSVGContent">
    <svg-each-path>
        <!-- call transclude once per path found -->
    </svg-each-path>
</div>
```

But inside svg-each-path, while I have a separate scope for each element, the `el` parameter to the directive is meaningless. Or it still points to the parent div or something.

I would like to do this:

```
<div svg-canvas="urlToSVGContent">
    <svg-each-path ng-click="onPathClick()">
    </svg-each-path>
</div>
```

This is what `svg-each-path` looks like currently:

```
function svgEachPath() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: 'element',
        priority: 1000,
        terminal: true,
        link: link,
    }    

    function link(scope, el, attrs, ctrl, $transclude) {
        // scope.paths was set by the svg-canvas directive
        scope.paths.forEach(function(path) {
            var childScope = <InnerScope> scope.$new()
            childScope.path = path

            // how can I change "el" to point to path?
            // or get the clone to be a clone of the path instead of the parent element?
            $transclude(childScope, function(clone) {

            })
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: how about using `replace: true`? (assuming the template has a single root element). that way `el` would point to the actual path element in each scope.

Comment: There's no template. I'm loading dynamic SVG content then I want to add behaviors to every `<path>` tag found inside it. I can't predict the paths that will be in the content.

Comment: It's sort of like I want `svg-each-path` to be a proxy tag for the real `path` tags found in the content.

Comment: this is why i suggested it. if you replace the root element for each `svg-each-path`, you'll get a reference to the `path` element in the linking/compiling functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking for the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) service. It lets you take any html string or element, and bind it to a scope to run directives. It doesn't require transclude at all.

```
function svgEachPath($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        // should stop processing directives. we don't want ng-click to apply to the fake element
        terminal: true,
        priority: 1000,

        link: link,
    }    

    function link(scope, el, attrs) {
        scope.paths.forEach(function(path) {
            // copy in all my attributes to the element itself
            Object.keys(attrs)
            .filter((key) => key[0] != "$")
            .forEach((key) => {
                // use snake case name, not camel case
                path.attr(attrs.$attr[key], attrs[key])                
            })

            // "compile" the element - attaching directives, etc
            var link = $compile(path)
            link(scope)
        })
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div svg-canvas="urlToSVGContent">
    <svg-each-path ng-click="onPathClick(...)">
    </svg-each-path>
</div>
```